# Как сделать бейдж на блок / кнопку с верхнего правого края?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как можно сделать нечто похожее в верхнем правом углу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это делается с помощью `position: relative;` или есть более правильное решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#content {
    position: relative;
}
#content img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

<div id="content">
    <img src="images/ribbon.png" class="ribbon"/>
    <div>some text...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Это обычно делаться при помощи [псевдоэлементов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), таких как `before` или `after`:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4285F4;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

div::after {
  content: "ХИТ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: initial;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>PREMIUM</div>
```

*Это может быть `div`, `button`, или что то иное, общий принцип все равно будет тот же.*